# Is the user-mode display driver required for a WDDM driver?

Tags: windows, driver, miniport

According to the "[Windows Vista and Later Display Driver Model Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff570589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)", there is a channel between application and display miniport driver like this:

> Application <---> user-mode Win32 GDI <---> kernel-mode Win32K.sys
>   <---> Dxgikrnl.sys <---> Display Miniport Driver

which doesn't need the user-mode display driver.

I am wondering that is it possible to supply a miniport driver only to support a simple framebuffer-based graphic card?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The title and the question seem disconnected from each other

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is YES. Since WDDM1.2 it provides you the option that just support a display only driver, which is basically a framebuffer driver without any 3D support. However, you definitely need a user mode driver to interact with d3d runtime and implement a full set of miniport DDI functions, if you would like to see D3D application running.

Answer (score 0):

Under some [specific circumstances](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/45d4c1d4-d692-4cdf-9a0e-ab9c5f13b318/is-user-mode-driver-mandatory-for-wddm-11-driver-model), at least on Windows 7 (and Vista I guess?) it is possible not to need it.

Aero has to be disabled though, nothing has to be using DXVA or anything fancy 3D and you may need a dummy dll to make the OS happy.